# How to configure ServiceStack.Text JsonSerializer property names when deserializing

Tags: .net, json, serialization, servicestack

I'm trying to deserialize JSON data using the `ServiceStack.Text` library with non-C#-like property name conventions, specifically snake case like the following:

```
{
    "first_name": "Foo",
    "last_name": "Bar"
}
```

I want to deserialize this into a POCO:

```
public class MyDto
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

I'm currently just doing this:

```
var dto = JsonSerializer.DeserializeFromString<MyDto>(dtoData);
```

but this won't recognize the property names. I've previously overcome this in `Newtonsoft.Json` using a [custom `ContractResolver`](https://gist.github.com/roryf/1042502). How should this be done using `ServiceStack.Text`?

I'd prefer not to decorate my dto class with `DataMember` attributes as this seems like a concern of the source of the data, not the dto itself, and should therefore be handled by the code performing the deserialization.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Look at [JsConfig](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Text/JsConfig.cs) for all the different configuration and customizations that [ServiceStack's JSON and text serializers](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Text/JsConfig.cs) supports, e.g:

```
JsConfig.Init(new Config { TextCase = TextCase.SnakeCase });
```

Should do what you want.

Comment: Thanks, this looks what I need. I only need to configure it for certain dto types and `EmitLowercaseUnderscoreNames` appears to be missing from that config method, will try and put together a pull request to fix this today.

Comment: Weird that I had to use this all of a sudden. I wonder if an update somewhere might have caused the default value to change.